# Handling oauth2 authentication the angular way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0

I have a backend service that serves up an OAuth2 authenticated API.  I am building a separate frontend in angular (to which I am new), and that frontend will have to authenticate all requests against that API.

Currently, my code is a mess and very non-DRY and non-modular.  I am looking for a guide on how to do this the angular way (whether that is through a certain coding style or using a common popular package).  I need to intercept each HTTP request, inject tokens in the header, and redirect to the login page if we receive an not-authorized response from the server.  It makes sense to store the token in local storage, as well, I think.

I didn't include a question mark there, so here goes: What is the best-practice angular way for authenticating all communications against an oauth2-protected API?

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard approach is to use $http interceptors as you have identified. I have used [this library](https://github.com/iandotkelly/angular-basicauth) in the past for similar purpose.

The authentication code is nicely encapsulated by the library and is very DRY.